# Angular 8. Unknown amount of http.get requests in array to call, must be sequential, what to use

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I used zip, but as it turned out, zip does it's work parallel, at least how I use it, and I need the calls to be sequential. Is there sth. in rjxs aleady ?

Otherwise I would build a recursive function, that shifts a call from the array and then returns that call piped with concatMap with a return to the same function.

But if there is some rjxs operator already, I'd prefer that of course.

This is my code

```
    private mapChildrenOfNode(sourceNode: TreeNode, trx: number) {
        const nodeId = sourceNode.id;
        const urlChildren = config.apiUrl + `/get_children/trx=${trx}&id=${nodeId}`;

        if (sourceNode.children == null || 0 === sourceNode.children.length) {
            return of(sourceNode);
        }

        return this.http.get<TreeNode[]>(urlChildren).pipe(
            map(
                children => {
                    sourceNode.childrenNested = children ? children : [];
                }
            ),
            map(
                () => sourceNode
            ),
            concatMap(
                node => {
                    return zip(...sourceNode.childrenNested.map(
                        childNode => {
                            return this.parseNodeAnswerRecursively(childNode, trx);
                        }
                    )).pipe(
                        map(children => sourceNode.childrenNested = children),
                        map(() => sourceNode),
                    );
                }
            )
        );
    }
```

## Update 1

I've seen now also that zip fires all preflights first, and when finished it goes for the data-requests... can't use that. I'm searching for sth. that is like zip also taking an array of observables (in my case array of http.get<>(url).pipe() calls) BUT calls them one by one.

## Update 2

I've found a solution and wrote an answer...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57556297/317083

Comment: `I used zip` the code would be helpful

Comment: I think concatMap is the better solution to your problem

Comment: zip(...callArray$). it seems that he starts them in the right order, but I see calls that fire, before first calls are finished. ok, maybe I'm wrong, because right now I'm not sure if the API / server I'm using is having problems and doing strange stuff or if it's my code. Please Standby, and don't vote me down. To give you a complete code fragement is difficult, because right now, everything is kind of spaghetti because of searching and testing (it's a big big nested tree, with different branch-types, with so many url's and lots of nested children that I need to fetch, very ugly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for an answer to the same problem. This is what I came up with in the end...

```
export function concatWalk<T>(observables: Observable<T>[]): Observable<T> {
    const observablesClone = observables.slice(0) as Observable<T>[];
    return iterate(observablesClone);
}

export function iterate<T>(observables: Observable<T>[]): Observable<T> {
    const anElement = observables.shift();
    if (observables.length === 0) {
        return anElement;
    }

    return anElement.pipe(
        concatMap(
            (result) => {
                return iterate(observables);
            }
        )
    );
}
```

And I would use it like this:

```
private mapChildrenOfNode(sourceNode: TreeNode, trx: number) {
    const childrenCalls$ = sourceNode.childrenNested.map(
        childNodeId => this.convertIdToObjectFetch(childNodeId, trx)
    );
    concatWalk(childrenCalls$);
}
```

---

**But** some time later, I discovered async await and refactored a lot, so now the above would look sth. like this

```
private async mapChildrenOfNode(sourceNode: TreeNode, trx: number) {
    const childrenCalls$ = sourceNode.childrenNested.map(
        childNodeId => await this.convertIdToObjectFetch(childNodeId, trx).toPromise()
    );
}
```

*But mostly I use it like this*

```
    async getGraphValues(treeNode: TreeNode, timeSpan, raster: Raster = Raster.MINUTE_15) {
        const x = await this.getAxisValues(treeNode, 'x', timeSpan, raster).toPromise();
        const y = await this.getAxisValues(treeNode, 'y', timeSpan, raster).toPromise();
        const z = await this.getAxisValues(treeNode, 'z', timeSpan, raster).toPromise();
        const w = await this.getAxisValues(treeNode, 'w', timeSpan, raster).toPromise();

        return {x, y, z, w};
    }
```

*or like this*

```
    async reloadAndMapNodeData(treeNode: TreeNode, timeSpan: TimeSpan) {
        const trx = await this.dataService.transactionBegin().toPromise();
        const refId  = treeNode.reference_object_id;

        await this.loadAndMapStructureObjectData(treeNode, trx).toPromise();
        await this.loadAndMapStructureObjectCollectionData(treeNode, trx).toPromise();
        await this.loadAndMapSankeyNode(treeNode, trx).toPromise();

        await this.dataService.transactionClose(trx).toPromise();
    }
```

It's much cleaner and easier to read. Before often I would have big nested calls like this (plus in these nested structure calls to other methods with nestings themselves)

```
x.pipe(
    map(
        () => y.pipe(
            map(
                () => z.pipe(
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're asking this because the functions to call are heavy and you need to release the main thread to the UI. :)

For a similar task i created a chain of promises.
Something similar to the following (pseudo)code.

```js
let p = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(true)
})

funcArray.forEach( (func) => { 
    p = p.then(func)
})
```

This simulates a task queue.

You can also write a more compact and readable version of this like the following:

```js
async function runArray(fArray) {
    for (let i=0; i<fArray.length; i++) {
        let f = async () => {
            return fArray[i]();
        }
        await f();
    } 
}
```

**Please note** the latter is not the same code as the former as in this case you run all the funcs in the provided array. In the first example you keep a queue working and you can add tasks wherever you like just by calling `.then(...)`.